# How to put a widget into any column inside a grid?

Tags: c, grid, gtk, position, gtk3

I'm writing by hand an application that use `Gtk+`. I'm using a `GtkGrid` to hold my `GtkWidget`s, but I can't put a `GtkWidget` into specific colum, as the second parameter of `gtk_grid_attach()` function says. E.g, the last element was placed into the 4-column, if I try to put into the 6-column it does not works; the `GtkWidget` is auto placed by the gtk into the 5-column.

Comment: You should show some code. The locations are 0-based, perhaps that is what is causing the confusion?

Comment: but it means can't I put a GtkWidget into 0-column and the next into 2-column making 1-column "empty"?(no widgets)? put a label without text make the visual effect that I want. Just like a new line, \n. Is needed really some code? I'II provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to have some blank space between the widgets, you should be able to achieve that with someting simpler. Like a plain `GtkBox`, and using the padding support when adding the widgets.

Comment: Thanks. I'II check out. See,is put a `gtk_label_new(NULL)` a ridiculous solution? modify the application to use GtkBox instead of GtkGrid can take too time, that I don't have.

Comment: Yes, using a blank label as a spacer is ridiculous. Use margin and padding properties instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just "skip" a column, this has no meaning. An empty column is just 0 pixels wide. You need to put something there, either in the same row, or in another, if you want it to have a width > 0. You can just put a GtkFixed widget there if you want, but if this is just to separate 2 widgets, you may want to use the row-spacing and/or column-spacing properties instead. The official GTK documentation gives some advice about [how GtkGrid works](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/ch30s02.html).